# (Android, Firebase) databasereference.push().setValue() not working even though log says otherwise

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I'm testing Firebase by building an app that simply puts a message in the Database (authorisations are set to true for the test), it worked only once, and now nothing is pushed to the database. But as you can see I put logs everywhere to see where the problem is and surprisingly the `onChildEventListener()` seems to notice a change.

Here is the code for my main activity :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public final static String TAG = "Main Activity";

    public final int[] id = {0};

    Button sendButton;

    EditText messageEditText;

    String message;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        id[0] = 0;

        sendButton = findViewById(R.id.send_message);

        messageEditText = findViewById(R.id.message_text);

        final DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("test/geomessage/");

        sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                message = messageEditText.getText().toString();

                Log.e(TAG, "Test 1");
                GeoMessage currentGeomessage = new GeoMessage(id[0], message);

                Log.e(TAG, "Test 2");

                databaseReference.child("children").push().setValue(currentGeomessage).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Success !");
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "FAIL");
                    }
                }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Complete");
                    }
                });

                Log.e(TAG, "Test 3");
            }
        });


        databaseReference.child("children").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                Log.e("101", "Child Added !");
                id[0] = (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                Log.e("101", "Child CHanged !");
                id[0] = (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });


    }


    private static class GeoMessage {

        int id;
        String content;

        public GeoMessage() {};

        public GeoMessage(int id, String content) {

            this.id = id;
            this.content = content;

        }

        public String getContent() {
            return content;
        }

        public void setContent(String content) {
            this.content = content;
        }
    }

}
```

Here are the logs when I click on the "Send" Button :

```
11-03 19:02:13.338 7440-7440/com.example.brumor.geofiretest E/Main Activity: Test 1
11-03 19:02:13.338 7440-7440/com.example.brumor.geofiretest E/Main Activity: Test 2
11-03 19:02:13.340 7440-7440/com.example.brumor.geofiretest E/Main Activity: Test 3
11-03 19:02:13.420 7440-7440/com.example.brumor.geofiretest E/101: Child Added !
```

Comment: i notice that there isn't a `log` statement for "Success" or "FAIL" or "Complete"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The observed behavior occurs when the device does not have a connection to the Firebase servers.  Calls to `setValue()` [change the DB cache held locally](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#write_data_offline) in the client.  This causes listeners for the changed location to fire.  But the completion listeners for `setValue()` do not fire until the update to the Firebase server completes successfully or fails.

Check that your device has a network connection.  You can detect the Firebase connection status using [the example here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-connection-state).

Comment: Indeed it is not connected, I just have to figure out why... Any hints? Thanks a lot anyway!

Comment: @Brumor: Check the logcat output.  Are you sure you have a network connection (wifi or cell)?

Comment: Tried with a different Emulator and it worked! Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

```
  sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            message = messageEditText.getText().toString();

            GeoMessage currentGeomessage = new GeoMessage(id[0], message);
      databaseReference.child("children").push().setValue(currentGeomessage);

        }
    });
```

No need to use `addonSuccessListener` to store data. Also it is not even entering the method `addonSuccessListener` , so its skipping the whole method and then it prints the Log for you, but nothing is entering the database. Usually `onSuccessListener` is used for firebase storage, to see if the task is successful or not.

Also according to this page: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/java/reference/com/google/firebase/tasks/Task

```
public abstract Task<T> addOnSuccessListener (OnSuccessListener<? super T> listener)
```

The above method is deprecated.

You have to use this now:

```
public abstract Task<T> addOnSuccessListener (Executor executor, OnSuccessListener<? super T> listener)
```

Comment: I added an OnSuccessListener especially to see if the task is successfull or not, and it doesn't show anything !